# How to filter dates from and to a particular date in Reactjs using mui datepicker

Tags: reactjs, date, filter, datepicker

I have an array of objects "mainData" like so:

```
0: {date: "2020-07-25T16:44:43.000Z"
description: "Qwerty"
id: 89329972},
1: {date: "2020-07-25T16:46:28.000Z"
description: "Place bins please"
id: 65586316},
2: {date: "2020-07-25T16:49:12.000Z"
description: "Solve sewerege problem"
id: 84687816},
3: {date: "2020-07-26T16:34:47.000Z"
description: "Test compl"
id: 56437370},
4: {date: "2020-07-26T16:34:47.000Z"
description: "Test compl"
id: 56437370},
5: {date: "2020-07-26T16:34:47.000Z"
description: "Test compl"
id: 56437370},
6: {date: "2020-07-27T08:40:34.000Z"
description: "Sewerage problem in my area"
id: 92402221},
7: {date: "2020-07-28T11:42:18.000Z"
description: "problem"
id: 25613902},
8: {date: "2020-08-09T11:42:18.000Z"
description: "problem"
id: 25613902},
9: {date: "2020-08-10T11:42:18.000Z"
description: "problem"
id: 25613902},
```

Now I am allowing the user to select from and to dates by using the mui datepicker. This is how I am receiving the values:

```
db date new : Sat Jul 25 2020 16:44:43
selected fromDate : Sat Jul 25 2020 22:46:00
selected toDate : Mon Aug 10 2020 22:46:15
```

The first db date is 25th where as the fromdate is also 25th but their values are coming different because of the difference in time/timezone.

This is what I used to filter out the values:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if (fromDate !== null && toDate !== null) {
            setReportData(
                mainData.filter(
                    (obj) => {

                        console.log("db date new :", new Date(obj.date.substring(0, 19)))
                        console.log("selected fromDate :",fromDate)
                        console.log("selected toDate :", toDate)

                        
                        return new Date(obj.date.substring(0, 19)).getTime() >= fromDate.getTime() && new Date(obj.date.substring(0, 19)).getTime() <= toDate.getTime()

                     
                    }
                )
            )

          

        }

    }, [toDate])
```

With this I don't get the objects with the date 25th but I do get the objects that matches the toDate and all the objects between those two dates.

Comment: well at your example `selected fromDate : Sat Jul 25 2020 22:46:00` is greater than `db date new : Sat Jul 25 2020 16:44:43`, so this date shouldnt be included :)

Comment: Yes exactly, that's the problem. It's because of the time right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to filter by date only and ignore time, you can do the following:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if (fromDate !== null && toDate !== null) {
        setReportData(
            mainData.filter(obj => {
                    return new Date(obj.date.substring(0, 19)).getTime() >= new Date(fromDate.getFullYear(), fromDate.getMonth(), fromDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0).getTime() 
                    && new Date(obj.date.substring(0, 19)).getTime() <= new Date(toDate.getFullYear(), toDate.getMonth(), toDate.getDate(), 23, 59, 0).getTime()

                 
                }
            )
        )
    }

}, [toDate])
```

So what you are telling your program is to take the `fromDate` and `toDate` objects and change their times in order to be at start and end of the day.
If you change your code to this, your filters will work. I couldn't find a property in MUI DatePicker in order to ignore the time.

```
new Date(fromDate.getFullYear(), fromDate.getMonth(), fromDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0)
new Date(toDate.getFullYear(), toDate.getMonth(), toDate.getDate(), 23, 59, 0)
```

The other alternative is to initialize the DatePickers' values with a date that includes time eg `2020-07-25T00:00:01` and then every date selected will "carry" this time.